# open versus fopen in C program (with multi-threading)

Tags: c, multithreading, fopen, fclose

For an unknown reason, it seems that fopen fails to open text files when it is called repeated times before closing.

My C program uses multithreading, and each thread handles one type of output text files (eleven per type), each type in a separated folder. I need to mantain these files opened during a long execution and at the same thread in order to write a lot of data.

To explain it better, the process is the following:

1- Thread #1 starts and creates and writes 11 files in one folder.

2- Without closing previous files, Thread #2 starts and creates and writes another 11 files in a different folder.

3- The same with other two Threads.

4- In the end, when all the files needed have been created and all the Threads have finished unless the main one, all the files are closed.

However and surprisingly, open is do able to handle all this files at the same time. Does anybody have a tip about this issue with fopen? I don't know if it is related with the multi-threading or with a max number of files that fopen can handle at the same time.

I am in Windows platform with Borland compiler.

Comment: Which compiler and OS do you use? Can you please post some code?

Comment: Borland in Windows. It is not easy to post the code as it is very long. But I will try to summarize some of it.

Comment: If the code is long your problem could arise from a bug elsewhere in your code. Try to write a small self-contained example that evokes the behaviour. I haven't used Borland, but opening 44 files at once using `fopen` shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: What error are you getting from `fopen`? (Note: "I didn't check the error code" is not a sufficient answer.)

Comment: I tried, and I get a 0 for some files, and different than 0 for others. It seems that fopen is not able to open all the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very unlikely that the problem is with `fopen`. `fopen` uses `open` underneath and the maximum number of open files most probably has the same limit as `open`.

My guess is that you have an error somewhere else, most likely going out of an array boundaries.

If you are not using any Windows specific functions, you could always [`valgrind`](http://www.valgrind.org/) it on Linux.

If you can't port the code, you could binary search the error. For example, comment out half the code that writes to files and see if the problem persists. If it doesn't, the problem is *likely* on the part that is commented out. If not, the problem is on the part that is not commented.

Note the term "likely" above. If your code results in undefined behavior, you can't rely on the behavior. Even buggy code could behave correctly.

Comment: The problem is that the code is pretty big and commenting code could be very hard. The thing that I still don't get is why, under the same conditions, open "hides" the error, but fopen does not.

Comment: @cuartango, `open` returns a number and `fopen` returns a (pointer to) a structure. This means that the layout of the variables changes when you switch between the two, most likely because what `open` returns (`int`?) and pointers have different sizes on your computer. That means that what the code messes up is different between the two. So in one, you get lucky and not notice it, with the other you do.

Comment: open return is loaded into an int variable, while fopen return uses FILE* variable. Do you suggest that the problem could be in the FILE* variable declaration, or maybe other variables are affecting it due to a memory corruption for example?

Comment: @cuartango, usually with these kind of problems, there is a high chance of memory corruption.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK the f-functions aren't thread-safe. open may be the foundation for fopen but underneath it all are basically the (originally Win32) functions CreateFile, ReadFile, WriteFile and CloseHandle. They are thread-safe and I suggest you use them rather than using critical sections around your f-calls.

Comment: I think the info you provided could explain the issue. Some of my code uses CreateFile, I will check it to see if I can get anything.

Comment: I don't think mixing f-function and "low-level" Win32 function calls is a good idea at all. Choose one set or the other and stick with them.

Answer (score 1):

The C Run Time (CRT) library is thread safe from Windows XP and above.  Also, if you believe some of the comments in the CRT include files, it has a limit of 20 open files.

So, in your application.  What is the reason for a single thread to have 11 files open?  You are NOT going to get a measurable performance gain by writing them simultaneously.  In fact, you could make it worse because the C drive will thrash as it moves around trying to write each file.

Depending on how your application is designed:  open one file, write to it until full, close it, open second file, etc.

Now, multiply the possibility of disk thrashing by four as each thread is trying to do I/O to the same C drive!  So, serialize disk accesses if possible.  to get a real improvement increase the buffer sizes.