# Read a txt file line by line without using fopen()

Tags: c, file-processing

I need to read a text file line by line.

The problem is that in my code I cannot use `fopen()` and then `fgets()` to read the content of each line, because `fopen()` fails when I use a lot of threads (it seems that it gets overload because it is being opend so many times).

Comment: Use `open()`  and `read()`?

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot"? Says who?

Comment: But how can I change to the next line using read? read function reads all the characters along, but without changing line.

Comment: `read()` `char` by `char` until a new-line (`"\n"` or `"\r\n"` or ... whatever your file uses as line terminator).

Comment: Please add updates to your question to the question itself, but squezzing them into a comment.

Comment: unwind, sorry, I did not explained well. fopen fails when I use a lot of threads (it seems that it gets overload because it is being opend so many times)

Comment: @cuartango Why do you think switching from `fopen` to `open` is going to fix the errors in your thread based implementation.

Comment: Sounds like a bad implementation or design of your program.

Comment: Brandin, muy program uses multi-threading. When I run the program with 4 threads, all fopen work fine. But when I increase this number of threads, suddenly fopen does not work.

Comment: Try to find the cause, why `fopen()` does work for more then four thread, as it should be able to handle this perfectly well.

Comment: Two of his previous questions (1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18700785/open-versus-fopen-in-c-program-with-multi-threading (2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609512/fopen-does-not-deal-with-more-than-60-files-at-the-same-time

Comment: @alk, I will try what you suggested about the terminator. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use [getline()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/)
You would need to specify the delimiter and a while or for loop to stop when reach EOF.

EDIT: you said you dont want to use fopen() and fgets() and so :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  string line;
  ifstream myfile ("example.txt");
  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    while (! myfile.eof() )
    {
      getline (myfile,line);
     if (line = something)
      {
      // read next line and print it... but how?
      }
    myfile.close();
  }

  else cout << "Unable to open file"; 

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I doubt a call to `getline()` without having called `fopen()` on the `FILE*` passed in would work.

Comment: I cannot use fopen (thread problems). I can use ofstream maybe?

Comment: @cuartango: `ofstream` is C++, it's not available in C.

Answer (score 0):

Most operating systems have limits on how many files a particular process can open at the same time. Since `fopen()` is "just" a wrapper on top of `open()`, it won't help to use a lower-level interface if this is your problem.

You can verify that this is indeed your problem by checking `errno` when `fopen()` fails, i.e. if it returns `NULL`. You sound as if you've already done this, but you weren't very specific. I would expect `EMFILE` if you're running into the per-process limit (see the [`open()` manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/open)).

You need to investigate what your particular limits are and see if you can change them, or re-design your program so that you don't open as many files in parallel.

Comment: unwind, after a lot of investigations, the only thing we have found is that fopen fails when it is used so many times (due to multi-threading). I already changed fopen to open in binary files reading, the problem now is to read no binary files with open.

Comment: one time per thread, and it fails when I am using more than 4 threads. The thing is that fopen seems to overload when using it a lot of times when opening also different files.

Comment: @cuartango: What platform are you experiencing this on? For a standard PC even a really mature one 5 files opened in parallel shouldn't provoke any issues.

Comment: It's a modern PC, with Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

You can use open ([man open (2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html)) and read ([man read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html)).

What is the real problem with `fopen()`?

Comment: @cuartango which OS do you use, Windows, Linux or OS X?  (I guess it isn't BSD)

Comment: @cuartango I found the answer by myself!  You're on Windows with Borland, and have been annoyed by this problem for half a year! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18700785/open-versus-fopen-in-c-program-with-multi-threading

Comment: It is not the same problem, is a consequence ;)

Answer (score 0):

If open/read works and fopen/fread doesn't work, this may be because you're running out of lock structures. Using unlocked_getc in a loop (reading until you get a newline) might be the easiest option.

Answer (score 0):

Some folks recommended you to use `open(2)` and `read(2)` as replacements of `fopen(3)` and `fgets(3)`, but since they are Unix (Linux and OS X) API, you cannot use them with Borland on Windows.  What corresponds to `open(2)` and `read(2)` on Windows are Win32 APIs `CreateFile` and `ReadFile`

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467.aspx

But I really doubt this is the way to go for you...  You're trying to solve a problem which should never happen on a normal program.  You need to find the root cause of your problem.